# How can i read characters from a file and split it into two 16bits?

Tags: c

I want to read d characters of a file and split that into two 16bits say for example:

```
text[1]=0x7469206564616d20; 
text[2]=0x7469206564616d20;
```

How to do that?

INSTEAD OF TEXT[0] AND TEXT[1] PREDEFINED VALUES I WANT IT 2 READ D CHARACTERS FROM A FILE AND SPLIT IT IN2 THAT FORM

Comment: What do you mean by "split that into two 16bits" ? Can you show the output you require for your given example above ?

Comment: split into for xample: text[1]=0x7469206564616d20; and text[2]=0x7469206564616d20

Comment: then what is the input (since these two are the same)?

Comment: some text file. i want 2 read d characters and split them

Comment: i gave that as an xample i want that text1 and text2 to have d binary inputs from d text file

Comment: Sorry nobody, me included, seems to understand what you want. Please give us a very simple and clear example of what you want.

Comment: I want that 2 b used in dis program.. http://bloc.project.citi-lab.fr/codes/speck128_128.c

Comment: @user3437968: OK, thanks to the link you provided and your updated questions I probably guessed what you want, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thnks Mr. Michael Walz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
u64 text[2] ;

FILE *input = fopen("myfile.data", "r") ;

if (input == NULL)
{
  printf ("Unable to open file\n") ;
  return 1 ;
}

while (!feof(input))
{
  int charsread ;
  charsread = fread(text, 16, 1, input) ;  // read at most 16 bytes into the text array  

  // process your text array here
  // charsread contains the number of characters actually read
  //     this can be less than 16 if the total file length is not a 
  //     multiple of 16. You mus deal with that.

} 

fclose(input) ;
```

Comment: Will dis split d text file into two text0 and text1??

Comment: The first 8 characters of the file, go into `text[0]`, the next 8 characters of the file go into `text[1]`.

Comment: what if there are more than 16 characters?? Need some sort of loop then

Comment: If there are more than 16 characters in the file, you cannot put them into the `text` array as there is only room for 16 characters. You certainly need a loop to read more characters. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thnk again Mr. Michael Walz

Comment: I will check dis program if worked u hav helped me2 finish ma degree thnx a lot.